# Does Ubuntu automatically release memory allocated by a C program as the program terminates?

Tags: kernel, c

I have written a C program containing code allocating memory using the `malloc()` function. If I don't free up the memory using the `free()` function, will Ubuntu release it automatically?

Comment: It has nothing to do with Ubuntu, its kernel's responsibility.

Comment: @user: A particular version of Ubuntu must run on top of one of the  versions of Linux kernel. So it has something to do with Ubuntu so as to know whether the kernel it is running on releases the memory automatically or not.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes.

The kernel will release all the resources allocated by a program upon the program's termination.

This is done after the `do_exit()` function defined in `kernel/exit.c` has terminated its execution; the `do_exit()` function execution itself might be triggered by a number of events, most commonly by an explicit `exit()` syscall called by the program during its regular computation or by an implicit `exit()` syscall called by the program upon its termination (as the C compiler places an `exit()` syscall after `main()`'s return). Other reasons include the reception of an unhandable / not ignorable signal or exception.

The `do_exit()` function itself performs a number of tasks. After it has terminated its execution, the program's allocated resources are released by the kernel and returned to the system for further uses.

[Source](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=370047&seqNum=4)

Comment: But that is of course no excuse for "forgetting" the free() ...